# How can I organize a list of dates into month and day counts using Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a list of almost a million dates formatted as DD-Mmm-YYY. I would love to create a calendar heat map using [Seaborn's heatmap function](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to visualize the distribution of dates during the calendar year (regardless of year). I have figured out how to separate out Month and Day into separate columns so that I have:

```
In [8]: df.head()
Out[8]:
  original_date month day
0   05-Sep-2010   Sep  05
1   08-Apr-2010   Apr  08
2   03-Aug-2008   Aug  03
3   03-Feb-2008   Feb  03
4   14-Mar-2008   Mar  14
```

What can I do to this dataframe to get it into a format that has days of the month as columns, and months as row index? Here's what I'm looking for, but it was done without Pandas, using csv processing and nested dictionaries.

```
       01    02   03   04    05   06   07    08   09    10  ... 
Jan  1923   371  341  451   437  332  338   398  403   476  ...   
Feb   931   675  891  514   479  452  509   657  507   771  ...  
Mar  1370   906  737  594   469  458  524   368  430  2136  ...  
Apr  1433  1127  706  791   639  817  584   580  515   757  ...   
May  1666   885  884  697  1626  708  809  1053  826  1281  ...
```

I'd like to do this in Pandas to be able to filter by year, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would create a new dataframe that counts by month and day (excluding year)

```
new_df = []
for key, grp in df.groupby(['month', 'day']):

    month, day = key

    new_df.append({
        'month': month,
        'day': day,
        'count': len(grp)
    })
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

Then you can pivot this dataframe to give the format you want

```
new_df.pivot('month', 'day', 'count')
```